# Spring Security 4: Allowing anonymous access and authenticated access on same url

Tags: spring, spring-security, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey 2 application which I'm trying to secure using Spring Security 4 and HTTP Basic authentication.
The controller class is a Spring bean and is injected into the Jersey Rest Resource. I'm using Spring Pre-Post-annotations on the controller's methods and tried out the following configs:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<security:http>
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>
```

Problem: Works fine with http-basic authenticated users, the annotated methods (`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")`) are secured and only work when the correct credentials are provided. BUT: Anonymous access on other resources under /** is not possible anymore (which is correct, but which I want to have).

Using

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```

instead, every user is handled as anonymous, even though they are providing the correct credentials via HTTP Basic. So even a user with the correct role cannot access the annotated method, a AccessDeniedException is thrown.

What I want: Every user should be allowed to access all resources under "/**". If he's authenticated via HTTTP Basic and has sufficient rights, the annotated method can be called. If he's not authenticated or authorized, an AccessDeniedException should be thrown.

How do I have to configure the Spring security `<http>` section?

Comment: Since you mention AccessDeniedException, do you have any special handling of it?

Comment: Not yet. I'm planning to write an Jersey ExceptionMapper for AccessDeniedExceptions, so that a correct HTTP Response status code is sent back. But the problem is the fact that this exception is always thrown, although for correctly authenticated user. It seems that Spring's securityFilterChain removes the Authentication header from HTTP requests and handles every user as anonymous as soon as I use "permitAll" or "hasAnyRole('USER', 'ANONYMOUS')" or anything that allows anonymous access.